# CALayer random ordering in Cocoa (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation, calayer

This bug is driving me crazy... Each time I run my app from Xcode, my panel draws it's layers in a random order! Even though the subviews order is intact!!

The app is a status bar app, that displays a simple `NSPanel` when the user clicks the status item. The `NSPanel` is loaded from the nib, and I can't say I do any more than that!!

Am I doing anything weird with the `CALayer`s? Absolutely not... All I have in `KMStatusPanelView` is an overriden `-[NSView drawRect:]`. The `KMRootView` has the following:

In `KMRootVC`, which is the view controller of `KMRootView`, I have:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSAssert(self.view.layer, @"Layer not created");
    [self.view.layer setCornerRadius:18.0];
    [self _loadControllerAtIndex:0];
}
```

.. and in `KMRootView`, I override `-[NSView drawRect:]`, and also have:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSAssert(self.layer, @"Layer not found");
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
}
```

That's it! That's all the code related to the Core Animation layer, with the exception of the fact that I ticked the checkmarks in IB to create the layers for me, instead of calling `-[NSView setWantsLayer:]`.

Here is a log from two different runs (I have removed most of the irrelevant data):
Obviously, `KMRootView` should be at the bottom, as you can see from the `-[NSView subviews]` output.

#### Run with correct results:

```
$2 = 0x000000010029b260 <__NSArrayM 0x10029b260>(
<KMRootView: 0x10029c400>,
<KMStatusPanelView: 0x100248a30>
)

(lldb) po [[[self.window contentView] layer] sublayers]
$3 = 0x0000000100264e50 <CALayerArray 0x100264e50>(
<_NSViewBackingLayer:...; bounds = CGRect (0 0; 320 480); delegate = <KMRootView: 0x10029c400>; sublayers =...,
<_NSViewBackingLayer:...; bounds = CGRect (0 0; 320 488); delegate = <KMStatusPanelView: 0x100248a30>;...
)
```

#### Run with screwed up results:

```
$0 = 0x000000010023aa40 <__NSArrayM 0x10023aa40>(
<KMRootView: 0x102430f70>,
<KMStatusPanelView: 0x102430660>
)

(lldb) po [[[self.window contentView] layer] sublayers]
$1 = 0x000000010242d2c0 <CALayerArray 0x10242d2c0>(
<_NSViewBackingLayer:...; bounds = CGRect (0 0; 320 488); delegate = <KMStatusPanelView: 0x102430660>;...,
<_NSViewBackingLayer:...; bounds = CGRect (0 0; 320 480); delegate = <KMRootView: 0x102430f70>; sublayers = ...
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use IB to enable layer backed views nowhere in hierarchy, but in `awakeFromNib` call `setWantsLayer:YES`

Comment: It would be nice to add why this works .. Did you experience this issue, is it mentioned elsewhere, is there an obvious bug in enabling layers within XIBs that I'm missing?

Comment: i belive it is a bug in XCode, maybe there is some radar for it, but definitely solved the exact same issue for me...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it's certainly more informative than my answer

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate this solution, but at least it works:

```
NSView* view = self.contentView;
if (view.layer.sublayers[0] == self.frameView.layer)
{
    NSLog(@"WTF?");
}
[view.layer addSublayer:self.frameView.layer];
```

The code sometimes reaches the NSLog statement, and sometimes it doesn't. Either way, the last line ensures that the `frameView` (`KMStatusPanelView` if you have been following) 's layer is on top.